# How to address content security policy directive for React in production

Tags: reactjs, express, cross-domain, content-security-policy

I am building a React app with `create-react-app` which I serve the static build from a node/express server which also acts as my API gateway.

On the React app I have a sign in page where I render a random image from an external domain using the API endpoint they give for fetching random images. The image is set using the `backgroundImage` property in CSS-in-js.

In development, that page shows random images just fine, but in production I get the error message "Refused to load the image <IMG_URL> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:"." in the browser console.

I've looked into the issue and found that there are answers here recommending enabling CORS on the node server.

While, I think that approach might work, I want to avoid CORS, and changing policy directives, as much as possible.

My question is, is there a standard "React" way of making this possible? How do I show random images from an external domain on my production site?

I guess another equivalent way of posing the question is, how do I set the image `src` attribute in React for images hosted cross domain?

Any help on this greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: CORS and CSP are two totally different things. *"How do I show random images from an external domain on my production site?"* you set the right CSP configuration - if you're using Express, configure Helmet (if you're already using it note the default configuration changed in v4, as I found out in https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Content-Security-Policy, which may be why you're seeing this).

Comment: @jonrsharpe You're right. I am using helmet. I will try to implement that fix and see if it works. What would you recommend my config should look like? Or can I make helmet less restrictive since my site won't be taking user content? If you make it an answer, and it works, I could accept it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've modified the `directives` key to look contain these values, `defaultSrc: ["'self'"], objectSrc: ["'none'"], scriptSrc: ["'self'"], styleSrc: ["'self'", "https: 'unsafe-inline'"], upgradeInsecureRequests: []`. Is this fine?

Comment: I don't know, I would suggest testing it, but you don't set an imgSrc so I would guess not.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just ended up doing `app.use(helmet({ contentSecurityPolicy: false }) );` as per helmet docs since I don't really know much about CSP and my site does not take user content. Thanks for pointing out the case about helmet. That was precisely the problem. If you put this as an answer, I can accept it.